# Powershell Copy Recursive Creates a n Data folder

Tags: powershell, recursion, copy

```
$from = ".\test\Application Data\software1\config\1.0"
$to = ".\test\Profile2k8\Appdata"

$exclude = @("new.ini","new2.ini")

Get-ChildItem $from -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $to $_.FullName.Substring($from.length)}
```

When I run this script, it will copy the files but it also includes a n data folder in the destination path like this :

```
.\test\Profile2k8\Appdata\n Data\software1\config\1.0
```

Why is this folder being created, and how can I prevent this?

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Would changing `$_.FullName.Substring($from.length)`
to just `$_.Name` work as expected for ya?

Edit: Oh right, noticed the recursive bit now, that might change things.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line of code at the last as below and I hope it will work with that:

```
Get-ChildItem $from -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $to $_.FullName.Substring((Convert-Path $from).length)}
```

Your code is trying to get the length of the string `$from` (which contains only a relative path and not the full path), but actual path length is something more as it may be something like

```
"C:\test\Application Data\software1\config\1.0"
```

Comment: Now it just copy the content of
    .\test\Application Data\software1\config\1.0
directly in to :
    .\test\Profile2k8\Appdata

without creating the software\config\1.0 folders

Comment: do you mean to say that the recursive heirarchy is not coming up in the destination folder?

Comment: yes / no from ".\test\Application Data\software1\config\1.0"
below all the folders are being created but the \software1\config\1.0 part are not

Comment: Oh I got it. In that case u should change the `$from` variable as `$from = ".\test\Application Data" ` or if that is a problem you should create the folders required with command `New-Item -Name software\config\1.0 folders -Path $to -ItemType Directory`

Comment: yes i already did this `if (!(Test-Path $to)) {
 New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $to
}` now it works like a charm. thanks a lot :)